# Why does not R Chi2 algorithm discretize in the same manner as in the paper by Liu and Setiono?

Tags: r, feature-selection

As stated in R documentation ([discretization - R (from CRAN)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/discretization/discretization.pdf)), R package discretizion offers the function Chi2, which comes to life in the following papers:

Liu, H. and Setiono, R. (1995). Chi2: Feature selection and discretization of numeric attributes,
Tools with Artificial Intelligence, 388–391.

Liu, H. and Setiono, R. (1997). Feature selection and discretization, IEEE transactions on knowledge
and data engineering, Vol.9, no.4, 642–645.

I wrote the following R programming language code, in which I have set alpha and delta equal to the ones set in the papers above. Finally, the following code prints out the discretized dataframe. I used Iris dataframe, as in one of the examples in the two papers.

```
library(discretization)
data(iris)
df1 <- iris[FALSE,]
for(i in 1:nrow(iris)){
    if(i %% 2 != 0){
        df1 <- rbind(df1, iris[i,])
    }
}
chi2(df1, alp=0.5, del=0.05)$Disc.data
```

The two papers above state that, with alfa = 0.5 and delta = 5%, and that "the originally odd numbered data are selected for training (75 patterns) and rest for testing (75 patterns)". Iris attributes selected are only two. The point is that, observing the dataframe printed out by the last instruction, you can see that no attribute is removed. The discretized data frame still have 4 attributes discretized: if I correctly understood the above papers, Sepal Length and Sepal Width should have been both discretized in just one interval by Chi2 algorithm.

Comment: General suggestion without knowing the details in such cases is: first read the documentation carefully if any deviations from the original procedure are noted/explained. If not, contact the package's maintainer.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find explicit signals of deviations from original procedure, so that I wrote to the package's mainainer. I hope he will be not too much busy

Comment: I think this question will be a tumbleweed, unfortunately

Comment: Seems to be a cross-post to r-help: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-November/443356.html

Comment: I wrote that post, after ayone didn't reply here, @Helix123

Comment: The more I post, the more I should obtain. Isn't it so?

Comment: ...well no response in a couple of hours? You are using a lot of people resources by sending out your question to more than one channel in such a short time frame.

Comment: The question was submitted 2 days ago. If you look at stack overflow and cross validated mean time before first response, it is so much time...

Answer (score 0):

The decreSigLevel() function of phase1 and phase2 written in R code differs from the criteria discussed in the original paper.
Please review the contents of the original papers and R code again.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! When you answer a post, try to make it self-contained and helpfull. For more info, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer